# PHP MySQL Query that MAY contain data if present

Tags: php, mysql

My current query string is

```
    $var = '  fkMemberId = \'24\' AND month(DisallowTimeFrom) = \'10\' ';
```

Needless to say if no October in table then I get an empty result.

What I'm trying to achieve is ...

```
    $var = ' fkMemberId = \'24\' BUT MAY ALSO CONTAIN BUT IF NULL CONTINUE QUERY month(DisallowTimeFrom) = \'10\' ';
```

fkMemberId = \'24\' is a MUST

month(DisallowTimeFrom) = \'10\' is a MUST only if data present but if not continue

I have left out the rest of the query for brevity.

Comment: I have no idea what do you want... could you post an example?

Comment: Is `DisallowTimeFrom` coming from a LEFT JOIN? If so, put the month condition in the `ON` clause of the join rather than the `WHERE` clause of the main query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$var = ' fkMemberId = \'24\' AND (DisallowTimeFrom IS NULL OR month(DisallowTimeFrom) = \'10\') ';
```